# Convert date from serial number in csv file for mysql import

Tags: mysql, date, csv

I am trying to import data from a csv file to a mysql table.  One of the columns contains a serialized date (it came from another mysql table) which I need to convert to a format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000000.  An example serial date is "1389792682".  I tried converting in Excel but none of the custom formats recognize the number as a date - I believe because it's a date-time number.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can use this formula in order to convert this timestamp to a date. Supposing your timestamp is in A1 cell:

```
=((A1/3600)/24) + DATE(1970,1,1)
```

This is because Unix epoch is the time 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970.
And then chose to format your cell as a date.

The timestamp that you specifies in your question gives me:

year: 2014
month: 01
day: 15
h: 13:31

Answer (score 0):

1389792682 corresponds to 2014-01-15 05:31:22 -0800 (2014-01-15 13:31:22 UTC) in Unix/Linux time.

It can be converted to a date field with

```
DATE_ADD('1970-01-01', INTERVAL 1389792682 SECONDS)
```